# MVC - Cannot find View after form is being send

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have the following structure in my (mvc) application

-Views
--Home
---Index.cshtml

--User
---Change.cshtml

I am using a Form like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Change", "User", new { id = 2 }))
{
     // Code ...
}
```

if all textfields are filled, you can click on the submit-button. In the background, actions will be taken and the user is being taken back to the Home/Index.cshtml page.

My code for returning the 'View' looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Change(FormCollection collection)
{
  //logic....
  return View("Index", "Home");
}
```

The problem starts here. I cannot switch back to Home/Index. I get an error which says, the view cannot be found. It tries to look up in the Views/User for the Index, but not in Home. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the User controller so when you do the following:

```
return View("Index", "Home");
```

MVC will look for the `Index` page in the `Users` folder.  Specifying `Home` is not telling it to look into the `Home` Controller.  That parameter is reserved for the model.

I would not recommend routing from one Controller to another, however you could use

`RedirectToAction` which allows you to specify the action name and the controller, in your case:

```
return RedirectToAction("Change", "Home");
```

Comment: I see. Thank you for this tip. I haven thought about 'RedirectToAction'. Nonetheless, i am interested why routing between controllers should be avoided in your opinion? i can organize, split my application in several parts and can maintain it better (imo).